# Embed video from You tube not working

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, embed

have a requirement of embedding a video and displaying it on a android activity.
Following is the code:

```
 ....Some Code

    viewHolder.webView.loadData("<html><body>" + embedcode + "</body></html>","text/html", "utf-8");
    viewHolder.webView.setTag("<html><body>" + embedcode + "</body></html>");

...Some code
```

Where the "embedcode" id for example

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MCCVVgtI5xU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There is a problem though..when i view a embedd code from TEDX it works just fine
Ex:

```
<iframe src="http://embed.ted.com/talks/eli_beer_the_fastest_ambulance_a_motorcycle.html" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

But when i have a video from You tube it dosent work.!!
I assume it is due to the missing "http:" protocol in src of the i frame.
Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe is marking problem. Try writing embed like this:
String embed = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/MCCVVgtI5xU\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

Comment: try to add the complete path of embed url from the youtube like along with the http:. Why http: is missing in your code when you copy the embed url its there

Comment: agree with @RenanBandeira it can be the reason as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call Youtube app like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://MCCVVgtI5xU"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Where MCCVVgtI5xU is the video ID.

Answer (score 1):

Using WebView to play YouTube videos would require testing & debugging on devices across different Android OS versions and manufacturers, due to the difference in functionality and bugs between Android 2.x and 4.x.

A less bug-prone approach that gives you more control is to use [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to embed a YouTube video into your own app, they have also provided [a sample app](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) so it shouldn't be too difficult if you follow their steps.